# Does du or df perform caching?

Tags: files, filesystems, disk-usage

I was wondering if there is any caching done with these utilities.  I assume not, but not positive.  Are there any typical similar utilities that do use caching to speed up results on subsequent runs?

Comment: I don't think that dd/df are doing the caching themselves but it rather some part of the kernel does that automatically

Comment: Maybe you ask the question in view of an other problem. 
When a program writes large logfiles and keep the filedescriptors open, deleting the files will not help making space free.
The ugly program still has 'locked'the filespace.

Comment: @WalterA I am only asking out of curiosity, I dont have an issue with open file descriptors or unexpected output, but thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/how-to-cache-or-otherwise-speed-up-du-summaries) and [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83639/27191)

Comment: @yuval Thanks!  I have learned so much since I asked this ill-informed question (it's a little embarrassing to be reminded of this question, haha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for caching in `df` as `df` does a single `statfs()` call (per filesystem). And obviously this call does read files on disk and sum up their sizes... The filesystems (e.g. the kernel) keep track of the free space.

`du` uses (without being aware of that) the page cache all applications use. In order to cache explicitly between runs there would have to be a "du daemon" anyway.

Comment: `du` could have a cache without a daemon. All it has to do is store the directory sizes in a file somewhere, and then read back that file on next run. (not saying it does, just saying a daemon is not needed)

Comment: @Patrick But without something like inotify this would make caching a probability game.

Comment: Ah, thats why you meant daemon, so it could monitor real time. Yes, agree :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is caching at some level (command or perhaps OS or FS-driver level - probably one of the latter two if you ask me), although forgive me for not knowing more details:

```
d@s7/mp3Ϡϡ time du -sh /mp3/    
27G     /mp3/
du -sh /mp3/  0.01s user 0.03s system 32% cpu 0.112 total

d@s7/mp3Ϡϡ time du -sh /mp3/
27G     /mp3/
du -sh /mp3/  0.00s user 0.01s system 82% cpu 0.015 total

d@s7/mp3Ϡϡ time du -sh /mp3/
27G     /mp3/
du -sh /mp3/  0.00s user 0.01s system 86% cpu 0.014 total

d@s7/mp3Ϡϡ time du -sh /mp3/
27G     /mp3/
du -sh /mp3/  0.01s user 0.01s system 78% cpu 0.020 total
```

Results obtained on Ubuntu 15.04 with ext4 filesystem, kernel version 3.19.0-15-generic.

Comment: those margins are really tiny to meaningfully demonstrate caching performance. I would use a much larger directory

Answer (score -2):

confirm, it caches

see this:

```
$du -sh testUpload.txt
104M    testUpload.txt

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=testUpload.txt bs=1M count=50
50+0 records in
50+0 records out
52428800 bytes (52 MB, 50 MiB) copied, 0.0248501 s, 2.1 GB/s

$ du -sh testUpload.txt
104M    testUpload.txt

<b>

$ ls -al testUpload.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alfred alfred 52428800 Jul  4 11:50 testUpload.txt
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What system is this? What filesystem is `/tmp`? Which `du` is it?

Comment: What is this supposed to be showing?

Comment: showing du is caching it, and it does not reflect the "new" size immediately.

Comment: du is showing you the amount used. You wrote zeros to it, so it's a sparse file and didn't add any addition usage. To see the apparent size, use du --apparent-size testUpload.txt