# Cleaning cache (?) command du

Tags: performance, disk-usage, cache

Following [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127846/does-du-or-df-perform-caching)

I can reproduce that the first time I execute a `du` of a directory it takes longer than if I do it just after.

Where is this caching happening? How can I clean it? I would like to perform some performance tests about the time a directory is taking on giving its size by executing `time du -sh /home/user/directory`

Comment: Relative answer to your question you could find at:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/how-to-cache-or-otherwise-speed-up-du-summaries

Found that there is option to drop Filesystem cache at: proc/sys/vm/drop_caches